# how to create folders with ss3 Gallery module

Tags: php, web, content-management-system, silverstripe

**Hi**,
I'm using the ss3 gallery module on my silverstripe project and i'd like to know if is it possible to create many folders than can own pictures.

This is my situation :
- I have a project page holder which allows some project pages
- I have some project pages with some data and some pictures

When i create a new project page and that i add some pictures, the pictures go in the asset/bulkUppload folder, the problem is this folder own all my projects pages pictures. I'd like to create a picture folder by project page so when for example i have to display my project page info, i can find easily its pictures ans display them

Does anyone have a clue of how it'd be possible?

Thanks, Thomas

Comment: Can you post the link of the module? I had the same problem with this module (http://www.silverstriperesources.com/articles/silverstripe-3-gallery-plugin-module/) The easy solution is simply use this one https://github.com/cwsoft/silverstripe-cwsoft-foldergallery

Comment: Actually, i use the same module, so you just add the cwsoft module and you can create different folders for your pictures right?

Comment: Yes, you can see the demo image : https://raw.github.com/cwsoft/silverstripe-cwsoft-foldergallery/master/docs/cwsoft-foldergallery-frontend.png

Comment: Okay Thank you, I'm gonna try this out :)

Answer (score 0):

If your images are being uploaded in a `bulkUpload` folder it is likely that this module uses the `GridFieldBulkEditingTools` module (https://github.com/colymba/GridFieldBulkEditingTools).

If this is the case, you can add this line for each `GridFieldConfig`:

```
$config->getComponentByType('GridFieldBulkImageUpload')->setConfig( 'folderName', 'gallery/'.$this->ID );
```

This would save the images in numbered subfolders for each page under `assets/gallery`. But you can change `'gallery/'.$this->ID` to whatever you want...